# How to select the previous element of a given class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an UL list :

```
<ul>
  <li data-sel='foo'></li>
  <li></li>
  <li data-sel='foo'></li>
  <li class='selected'></li>
  <li data-sel='foo'></li>
 </ul>
```

I can access the first previous element of `li.selected` who do not have attribute `data-sel=foo` by using `:not` selector

```
var element = $('.selected').prev("li:not([data-sel='foo'])");
```

But how can i access the first previous element of `li.selected` who have attribute `data-sel=foo` ?

Comment: That's not how `.prev` works: http://api.jquery.com/prev/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
var element = $('.selected').prevAll("li[data-sel='foo']")[0];
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rKVvk/)**

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine:

```
var element = $('.selected').prev("li[data-sel='foo']");
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amaan/pxhRv/)

Comment: I don't think `.has` works: *"Reduce the set of matched elements to those that have a descendant that matches the selector or DOM element."*. http://api.jquery.com/has/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `:has` selector? http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

Answer (score 0):

That is how `prev()` works, you could use `prevAll()` like this:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Fnjh/)

```
$('.selected').prevAll('li').not('[data-sel="foo"]').first();
```

OR

```
$('.selected').prevAll('li:not([data-sel="foo"]):first');
```